# Docker daemon does not start or restart

Tags: go, docker, daemon, ubuntu-14.04

I am on ubuntu 14.04 and I also upgrade docker to recent version.

Whenever I do a `sudo /etc/init.d/docker start` I get a successful pid as follows,

`docker start/running, process 16267`

When I view the PID details, I see nothing -

```
ps -p 16267
PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

And when I try to do a `sudo docker version` I see the below -

```
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.2.1
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
2015/01/10 10:30:49 Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

The output of `sudo docker -d` is as follows,

```
[2015-01-12T21:05:59.889680188+08:00] [info] docker daemon:  ; execdriver: native; graphdriver: 
[2015-01-12T21:05:59.889800519+08:00] [83736c52] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
[2015-01-12T21:05:59.895688816+08:00] [info] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
[2015-01-12T21:05:59.904409095+08:00] [83736c52] +job init_networkdriver()
[2015-01-12T21:05:59.932947471+08:00] [83736c52] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)
[2015-01-12T21:05:59.933137366+08:00] [fatal] log.go:64 Could not locate dockerinit: This usually means docker was built incorrectly. See http://docs.docker.com/contributing/devenvironment for official build instructions.
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Has anyone overcome similar issues? I am not even sure when I should check for more logs on this. Any directions on this will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the output if you run docker daemon directly (not as a service? To run docker daemon: `sudo docker -d`

Comment: @jcortejoso have updated the question with output of `sudo docker -d`

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a corrupted install.

- Uninstall docker
- Make sure you don't have a dockerinit (updatedb / locate dockerinit) -> delete it
- Reinstall docker

This should do the trick.

If not, try uninstalling docker again and try with binaries from https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/.