# Correct way to start docker daemon listening to specific port

Tags: ubuntu, docker, port, bind, daemon

I´m new to docker and want to start it in daemon mode listening to a specific IP-adress and port. In the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/daemon/) it is said that this can be done by writing `sudo /usr/bin/docker daemon -H 0.0.0.0:5555`. It then says that I can list running containers with this command `docker ps`. If I try this I get the following message:

> Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
>
> - Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
> - Is your docker daemon up and running?

I cannot interact with it. I´ve searched for a solution but with no luck. Any suggestions?

P.S. How can I run this daemon in background? I tried appending an & but I´m stuck on the ouput till pressing ctrl+c.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "nohup" is what you are searching for. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408816/how-do-i-use-the-nohup-command-without-getting-nohup-out

Comment: The behavior depends on your Operating System. What OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I specified docker running on IP x and Port y, but docker then only listens to that socket. I had to add another -H flag with the unix socket in order to listen to local requests:

```
sudo /usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:5555 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) with docker-ce (`17.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial`) do the following to make docker listen to a TCP port instead of sockets.

Add a file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf` with the following content:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
```

Add a file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the following content

```
{
    "hosts": [
        "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"
    ] 
}
```

Reload (`systemctl daemon-reload`) and restart (`systemctl restart docker.service`) docker.

For reference: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25471

**EDIT:**

Be careful, so the demon will only listen to that network port ignoring local requests.
To make docker listen to both remote and local, edit daemon.json but keep the standard unix socket

```
{
        "hosts" : [
                "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
                "tcp://<docker-host-ip-or-localhost>:2375"
        ]
}
```

Docker daemon connection options [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#examples)

Answer (score 4):

On **Mac OSX** you'd run the Docker Quickstart Terminal App to see:

```
Machine default already exists in VirtualBox.
Starting machine default...
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
Setting environment variables for machine default...
```

...

```
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/


docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
```

now

```
docker ps
```

should work

On **Linux** e.g. Ubuntu prepending sudo might be necessary. 
E.g.

```
docker ps
```

will lead to:

```
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
```

but

```
sudo docker ps
```

will work.

See 
https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/

To check if your docker service is running you can call

```
 sudo service --status-all 2>&1 | grep docker
```

and it should show:

```
[ - ]  docker
```

Sometimes your docker instllation might be corrupt 
see:  [Docker daemon does not start or restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872283/docker-daemon-does-not-start-or-restart?rq=1)

Comment: I prepended sudo but this does not help. I get the following message: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?` However, your suggestion with `sudo service --status-all 2>&1 | grep docker` gives me the expected output. Here is how I installed docker (I do it via script): `sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`  `sudo -u root bash -c "echo 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main' >>  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"`

Comment: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D`   `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get -y install docker-engine` `sudo service docker stop` `sudo /usr/bin/docker daemon -H 0.0.0.0:5555&`   PS: How can I do a line break in comments?

Answer (score 1):

This thread is quite useful, so I'd like to contribute how to get this to work on Ubuntu `14.04.1 LTS` with docker `1.12.6-cs13` (*might* work with docker-ce versions just as well). The `systemd` approach (also `/etc/sysconfig/docker`) is not possible for this Ubuntu vintage, the official docker documentation as of this writing has no post-install guide for making docker daemon listen on network using `upstart` for Ubuntu `14.04.1 LTS`. I found that below approach works rather well:

create `/etc/default/docker`
 file with content
`DOCKER_OPTS = "-H tcp://MACHINE-IP:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"`

restart docker service `sudo service docker restart`. After doing this, docker daemon started listening on network and the daemon logs looked clean. Perhaps more experienced docker users can chime in if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Phoenix's solution was giving me error. So i found an alternate way-

I edited ***/etc/sysconfig/docker*** and changed the OPTIONS parameter

```
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled -H=unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H=0.0.0.0:2375'
```

then i restarted the docker daemon

```
systemctl restart docker
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running latest version of systemd so it can be done easily.

you need to create a service file for docker before that login with root and create configuration directory for systemd

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

next need to create a service configuration file to hold docker configuration

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/options.conf
```

paste the below lines

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

reload and restart docker daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

> One thing important here is this will bring docker daemon root user so you need to adjust user settings in service file if you have any compliance issues.

After this you can connect your

```
root@5e5b1f264a1c:~# curl 172.31.112.67:2375/v1.38/containers/json 
[{"Id":"c3c68fc119595ca6a92fbcbdaddfaa294150ed76ba80c3ffbb072411d5979dac","Names":["/nginx"],"Image":"nginx","ImageID":"sha256:51086ed63d8cba3a6a3d94ecd103e9638b4cb8533bb896caf2cda04fb79b862f","Command":"/docker-entrypoint.sh nginx -g 'daemon off;'","Created":1666081825,"Ports":[{"PrivatePort":80,"Type":"tcp"}],"Labels":{"maintainer":"NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"},"State":"running","Status":"Up 13 seconds","HostConfig":{"NetworkMode":"default"},"NetworkSettings":{"Networks":{"bridge":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"007a4ef79334ca4e38c80177b36e37275116e945612f7637cc9ee3baf72e741b","EndpointID":"39644cfe51205f14c0b88a4842dab817b2ea9fbd503d12dbf84265ba6b8987d5","Gateway":"172.17.0.1","IPAddress":"172.17.0.2","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:11:00:02","DriverOpts":null}}},"Mounts":[]}]
```